# Deactivate Jetty's default 404 error handler

Tags: spring-mvc, jetty, web.xml, jetty-8

I want to provide a custom 404 error page in my Spring 3.1 web application, but I cannot deactivate Jetty 8's default 404 error page.

Jetty 8, out of the box, provides a default 404 error page:
when visiting a Jetty-hosted website, and providing a URL path that is not handled by any servlet (e.g. by visiting `http://www.example.com/nonexisting` ), Jetty responses with *its own default HTML error page*:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /nonexisting. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

To replace this default behavior,

- [I've removed the `DefaultHandler` from my Jetty XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756211/923560),
- [I've edited my `web.xml` to include both Servlet 2.5 and Servlet 3.0 error handler locations pointing to `/error`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066536/923560),
- [I've set up a dedicated `@Controller` for handling the request to `/error`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252763/923560),

but my website still returns *Jetty's own default HTML error page*.

[Jetty 8's official documentation talks about setting up a "custom error pages"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Custom_Error_Pages), but the suggestions there say

- to configure a custom Jetty error handler (I don't want to do this, I want to do it inside my own Spring `@Controller` as mentioned above)
- to create a "catch all context and create a "root" web app mapped to the `/` URI." (I don't want to do this as inside my `web.xml` I have already mapped Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet` to /.

How can I turn off Jetty's default error handler and have the error handling be done as pointed out above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to add a custom `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler`.

If a user doesn't explicitly specify some `ErrorHandler`, the Jetty server instance seems to register a default `ErrorHandler`.

As outlined on https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#custom-error-pages, to register a custom `ErrorHandler`, you can follow the following steps.

1. Implement some `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler` subclass, e.g. `com.example.CustomErrorHandler`.
2. Make this subclass available to your Eclipse server instance, e.g. by bundling `CustomErrorHandler` in a `jar` file and then copying that `jar` file into the `${jetty.base}/lib/ext` directory.
3. Configure your Jetty server instance to have this custom `ErrorHandler` registered as a bean:

file `jetty.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
"http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- more configuration -->
   
  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.example.CustomErrorHandler">
        <Set name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Comment: It gives ClassNotFoundException even after putting jar into the lib/ext directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to define custom error pages -

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Custom_Error_Pages