# Removing powered by Jetty

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using Jetty server with embedded web app. However, whenever I hit any resource which is not present it serves a default page which shows a message "Powered by Jetty".

This page is being served from `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler.handle`.

I want write a custom handler for this, however while trying to register custom Handler in `jetty.xml` file, I am getting syntax exception and server doesn't start anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deactivate Jetty's default 404 error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202839/deactivate-jettys-default-404-error-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by doing some tweaks along with changes mentioned in [Deactivate Jetty's default 404 error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202839/deactivate-jettys-default-404-error-handler).