# How to hide/remove jetty version when getting HTTP ERROR 404 with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When user is accessing data that is not available in jenkins then user is getting 404 but it's also displying Jetty version, how I can remove this jetty version information from response data?

HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /jenkins/user. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins uses a "Winstone", which is (nowadays) just a wrapper around the Jetty servlet container. So your questions boils down to configuring the 404 message for Jetty. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352073/removing-powered-by-jetty) for information on how to do that.

However, it could be more easy to just switch to a different servlet container (like Tomcat) instead.