# Custom page for HTTP 404 page URL in Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins, jetty, http-status-code-404, crlf-vulnerability

My Jenkins is running on https://myhost:9043 using the standalone war on Linux with the below command.

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

However, when I try the following URL for say `https://myhost:9043/<any random text>` the resource uri is obviously not found.

The problem, however, is I get output in the browser as

```
HTTP 404 error URI not found Powered by Jetty://9.4.27.vXXXX
```

I wish not to reveal the Jetty version.

Is there a way to display a custom error page for incorrect URIs thus avoiding revealing the Jetty version? If not, can I somehow hide the Jetty version from being displayed to anonymous users?

I'm not a pure java programmer but just a DevOps admin.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but: 1) it looks like you're not alone with the problem (ok, this is actually a good thing) and 2) looks like the solution requires a bit of coding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202839/deactivate-jettys-default-404-error-handler :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the Jetty version with adding to your command line `-Djetty.version=NOTHING`
Otherwise I created the issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62890 to have a custom error page from users